# Configuring MariaDB logs to hunt down random MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql, mariadb, timeout

> The most common reason for the MySQL server has gone away error is that the server timed out and closed the connection.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html

There is a table with two columns/rows (`CR_SERVER_GONE_ERROR` and `CR_SERVER_LOST`) which I'm not sure how to configure MariaDB to log?

My question is how do I configure MariaDB to log information I need to know if a connection times out or another cause?

This error has only occurred once and I would like to create a condition to test a timeout if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable your MySQL `log_error` and look there for clues. In the vast majority of cases this is due to one of the following:

1) Session was idle for too long - check `wait_timeout` and `interactive_timeout` variables.

2) mysqld OOM-ed (ran Out Of Memory) and the thread was killed.

3) mysqld crashed (usually a bug)

4) Something between you and the server caused a TCP connection reset.

In all cases, there should be something in the error log.

Comment: Great, thanks for posting. I'll try this out this weekend. :-)